# How can I reduce the memory footprint of this numpy gradient descent code?

Tags: python, memory, numpy

I'm new to numpy and still can't understand how it handles memory. I know my code is not optimal in terms of memory but couldn't really think of other ways without understanding how the memory is handled. Here's the code:

```
# X.shape = (700, 23000)
# Y.shape = (700, 23000)
learning_rate=0.7
iters=100

W = np.random.random((Y.shape[0], X.shape[0])) - 0.5
num_examples = Y.shape[1]

for i in range(int(iters)):
    error = W.dot(X) - Y
    xerror = X.dot(error.T)
    d = (1.0 / num_training_examples * xerror).T
    W = W - (learning_rate * d)
```

The code works when the number of training examples is small (~1000), but when it's as big as 20K the memory explodes. Any help to optimise the memory footprint of this code is very much appreciated.

Comment: Where you say that X.shape = (700, 23000) that seems to mean you have a matrix of 700 rows and 23000 columns, is that what you actually mean? Or do you mean it's 700 rows in one case and 23000 rows in another case?

Comment: I think what @CrazyCasta is trying to get at is that you are taking the dot product of two large matrices, gradient descent may not be the best way to go when you have this large of a data set. There are other methods for finding minimums on such large data sets.

Comment: @CrazyCasta it is indeed a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by the memory "explodes". I believe numpy uses double for matrices and vectors. That means 8 bytes per number. Therefore a 20k x 20k problem is going to be 400M numbers or 3.2 GB. If that's what you mean then it's just a problem of scale (you have too big of a problem) and you need to find a different way to represent it if such memory uses are too large.

Based on your comment about X and Y being matrices. If your problem size is only 20k ish you can get some savings by only handling a column at a time of X and Y. At 23k rows that will reduce your memory footprint to 1/3. If you scale up to 46k rows that will be up to 2/3 (only a reduction of 1/3) and by 92k rows you'll only reduce to 16/18 (0.888).

Generally when you go to large problems you start dealing with things like iterative algorithms and sparse matrices to reduce the memory load. See for instance [conjugate gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).